# Kafka-Connect Docker container fails with JsonSchemaConverter

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

Hi I use Kafka connect docker container image `confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect` `5.5.3` and everything was running fine when using follwing Parameters

```
...
  -e "CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
  -e "CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
  -e "CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
  -e "CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
...
```

Now we introduced Schema Registry and decided to go with JsonSchemaConverter for now and not avro. I changed follwoing (INTERNAL stays as it is for now)

```
...   
   -e "CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER=io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter" \
   -e "CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER=io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter" \
   -e "CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL=http://<schemaregsirty_url>:8081" \
   -e "CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL=http://<schemaregsirty_url>:8081" \
...
```

Following Error appeared:

```
[2021-02-04 09:24:14,637] ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed)org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter for configuration key.converter: Class io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter could not be found.
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseType(ConfigDef.java:727)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parseValue(ConfigDef.java:473)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:466)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:108)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:129)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerConfig.<init>(WorkerConfig.java:374)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedConfig.<init>(DistributedConfig.java:316)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:93)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:78)
```

It seems the converter is not available here by default. Do I have to install JsonSchemaConverter? I thought it comes by default?

Comment: hey by any chance were you able to resolve this?